# Unwanted center alignment

Tags: html, css

I need to list several sections of `div` that has `display` parameter `inline-block`. As a group, I need them to be centered on screen, but I wish them to start on left of such group when a "new line" is needed.

Here is a very simple demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/fcdm56ra/

```css
div.c1 {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

div.c2 {
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  align: left;
}

div.c3 {
  border-color: #0f0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="c3">
      111111111111111111<br>abc
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      22222222222222222
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3333333333333333
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      444444444444444
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      55555555555555
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      6666666666666
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      777777777777<br>def
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

...but I would like to have it as the following:

[image]

And even more **ideal** result would be to have it displayed like this:

[image]

...where the height of the "22222222222222222" block was autosized to its line height, to match height of other element(s) in the same "row".

---

Important part is that as a whole block it has to be centered on the screen and the `c3` class has to be `inline-block`.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flexbox here and a couple defined max widths to achieve this result:

```
div.c1 {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 38ch;
}
div.c3 {
    border-color: #0f0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: 18ch;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pL2hog73/10/

**UPDATE**

Since you don't want to use Max-Widths you can try a grid approach. It doesn't exactly match your preferred output since the columns are a little more rigid.

```
div.c1 {
    background: #fff;
    display: grid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
div.c3 {
    border-color: #0f0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    grid-column: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: min-content;
}

div.c3:nth-child(even) {
    grid-column: 2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f1jt845a/1/

Alternatively you could also just let the `.c3` divs be `width: min-content; display: inline` and just insert a `<br/>` after every two. This would give you the left alignment you want without having to deal with grid/flexbox.

Comment: Without `max-width` it does not center the entire content as requested. I don't want to limit the width.

Comment: I moved the max-width to a "width: min-content" should allow the width to grow while also keeping the box tight around the text.

Comment: The container simply has a width on it because I needed to center the container in jsFiddle. I don't know what the rest of your HTML looks like but you can easily remove that width rule and center the container on your page another way. Like: https://jsfiddle.net/3mL40w62/3/

Answer (score 0):

You should have the parent `c2` as `inline-block` also:

```
div.c2 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: No. https://jsfiddle.net/hkxb64y5/ - it wouldn't be centered on the screen then